# C program to remove all spaces from a given string prints some extra text despite exiting loop

Tags: arrays, c, string, loops, c-strings

I have written a program to remove all spaces from a given string, and have used a loop to iterate over the string to move over the spaces and add the text in a new string. The code does this but also prints some extra text (last few chars from the original string) despite it not being in a loop and not being added to the new string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char str[] = "   My name is Harry   123 "; //Initial string
    char newStr[] = "";    //New string with no spaces
    for(int i = 0, j = 0;i<strlen(str);i++){   //running a loop with i and j to check 
                                                and move over spaces and only add text 
                                                 in newStr
        if(str[i] == ' '){
            continue;
        }
        else{
            newStr[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",newStr); //Printing the newStr
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

[image: MynameisHarry123arry 123]

I also want to point out that my program runs fine if I set a size to the newStr or if I use "i<=strlen(str)" instead of "i<strlen(str)".

Comment: `char newStr[] = ""` That creates an array that can only store one char, that is, only an empty string. Writing beyond that as your code does is Undefined Behaviour. Make the array big enough to fit the result string.

Comment: But why does it work when I write "i<=strlen(str)" instead of "i<strlen(str)"?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour. UB means the result is unpredictable. Can crash, can produce wrong results, can even appear to "work" sometimes. But the result can change at any time and with any unrelated code or environmental changes.

Comment: When you do `<=`it copies the 0x00 string terminator (serendipitously). Independently, you _do_ have UB as kaylum said so do (e.g.) `char newStr[1000] = ""`

Comment: Better to use `char newStr[sizeof str];`

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because strings in c the last byte they store is '\0' that indicates the end of the string.

for "Harry" it would be like "Harry\0"

the problem is that strlen() only gives the number of characters before the '\0'. **You are printing out garbage because the string you built wont have the '\0' character at the end. But with <= you read in that null character too which does not equal ' ' and puts it into you newStr[].**

I hope that this will be helpful to you!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to dynamically allocate in memory newStr while building it or give it a big enough size at the initialization, because right now it's only 1 byte long ('\0') and any attempt to write more than that will throw a valgrind invalid write error that could segfault.

Then when you've finished copying it you must put at the end a '\0' to prevent any attempt of reading it to overshoot (like printf might do).

Example with reallocation :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char str[] = "   My name is Harry   123 ";
  char *newStr = NULL;
  int j = 0;

  for (int i = 0, len = strlen(str); i < len; i++) {
    if (str[i] != ' ') {
      newStr = (char *)realloc(newStr, sizeof(char) * (j + 2)); // new char and '\0'                             
      newStr[j] = str[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  newStr[j] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", newStr);
  free(newStr);

  return 0;
}
```

Example with pre-allocation :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char str[] = "   My name is Harry   123 ";
  char *newStr = NULL;
  int lenNewStr = 0;
  int j = 0;

  for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    if (str[i] != ' ') lenNewStr++;
  newStr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (lenNewStr + 1));

  for (int i = 0, len = strlen(str); i < len; i++) {
    if (str[i] != ' ') {
      newStr[j] = str[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  newStr[j] = '\0';

  printf("%s\n", newStr);
  free(newStr);

  return 0;
}
```